# MSBuild - How to dynamically include generated *.razor files

Tags: razor

It seems the following csproj is including my generated .razor files as it complains of duplicates if I run it twice.
What it is not doing is generating the g.cs files or compiling them into the project.
If I rebuild they are included but my requirement is to generate and build in one step.
The generator is a command line generator MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler

I have been trying to sove this for 3 days so any help greatly received

```xml
<!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference -->
<!--Use: dotnet msbuild -preprocess:<fileName>.xml to evaluate this project-->
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <!--Make sure this projects build targets run before other referenced projects-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      CompileDocs;
      $(BuildDependsOn)
    </BuildDependsOn> 
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--Outside Visual Studio SolutionDir is not available-->  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition=" '$(SolutionDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\</SolutionDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--Look for a compiled version of this project for performance-->
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler.dll')">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <RunCommand>dotnet "$(SolutionDir)MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler.dll"</RunCommand>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler/bin/Debug/net5.0/MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler.dll')">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <RunCommand>dotnet "$(SolutionDir)MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler/bin/Debug/net5.0/MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler.dll"</RunCommand>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <RunCommand>dotnet run --configuration release --project "$(SolutionDir)MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler/MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler.csproj"</RunCommand>
      </PropertyGroup>     
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>

  <!--Execute the code generator-->
  <Target Name="CompileDocs" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild" DependsOnTargets="IncludeGeneratedFiles">
    <Message Text="Generating Docs and Tests using $(RunCommand)" Importance="high"/>
    <Exec Command='$(RunCommand)' />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;LIVESHARP_DISABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--Because we have a dynamic content .cs and .razor files comming from the code generator 
  we need to start from no content and recreate MSBuild rules so evreything is included.
  If we dont do this the compiler takes 2 passes to compile all the content-->  

  <Target Name="IncludeGeneratedFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Models\Snippets.generated.cs" Condition="!Exists('Models\Snippets.generated.cs')" />
      <Compile Include="Models\DocStrings.generated.cs" Condition="!Exists('Models\DocStrings.generated.cs')" />
      <RazorComponent Include="**/*ExampleCode.razor" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-5.0 -->
  <Target Name="ExampleCode" BeforeTargets="PrepareForRazorComponentGenerate" >
    <ItemGroup>
      <RazorComponent Include="**/*ExampleCode.razor" Condition="!Exists('Models\DocStrings.generated.cs')" />
      <Content Update="$(_RazorComponentInclude)">
        <Generator>MSBuild:RazorGenerateComponentDeclarationDesignTime</Generator>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
 

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data\Elements.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MudBlazor\MudBlazor.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing

The most important bit is

`<RazorComponent Include=`

```
<!--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference -->
<!--Use: dotnet msbuild -preprocess:<fileName>.xml to evaluate this project-->
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <!--Make sure this projects build targets run before other referenced projects-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      CompileDocs;
      $(BuildDependsOn)
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--Outside Visual Studio SolutionDir is not available-->  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir Condition=" '$(SolutionDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\</SolutionDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunCommand>dotnet run --configuration release --project "$(SolutionDir)MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler/MudBlazor.Docs.Compiler.csproj"</RunCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>   

  <!--Execute the code generator-->
  <Target Name="CompileDocs" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild">
    <Message Text="Generating Docs and Tests using $(RunCommand)" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="$(RunCommand)" />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;LIVESHARP_DISABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--This file contains any ExampleCode that is new and needs including in the build -->
  <Target Name="ReadFromFile" DependsOnTargets="CompileDocs">
    <ItemGroup>
      <NewFiles Include="NewFilesToBuild.txt"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ReadLinesFromFile
      File="@(NewFiles)" >
      <Output
        TaskParameter="Lines"
        ItemName="NewExampleCodeToBuild"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
  </Target>

  <!--Because we have a dynamic content .cs and .razor files comming from the code generator we need to add them -->  
  <Target Name="IncludeGeneratedFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforeRebuild" DependsOnTargets="CompileDocs;ReadFromFile">
    <Message Text="Found '@(NewExampleCodeToBuild->Count())' new ExampleCode files" Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Models/Snippets.generated.cs" Condition="!Exists('Models/Snippets.generated.cs')" />
      <Compile Include="Models/DocStrings.generated.cs" Condition="!Exists('Models/DocStrings.generated.cs')" />
      <RazorComponent Include="@(NewExampleCodeToBuild)" Condition="@(NewExampleCodeToBuild->Count()) != 0" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data/Elements.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BlazorInputFile" Version="0.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="../MudBlazor/MudBlazor.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```